# unable to compile application project on sdk 2019.1

Tags: c, sdk, program-entry-point, xilinx

I made hw design on vivado 2019.1 and i build application project on sdk 2019.1 based on .hdf file.
(My design consists of microblaze mcs)
i have 2 static libraries too .

When i try to compile main() it gives me an error:
c:/tmp/sdk/2019.1/gnu/microblaze/nt/bin/../lib/gcc/microblaze-xilinx-elf/8.2.0/../../../../microblaze-xilinx-elf/bin/ld.exe: c:/tmp/sdk/2019.1/gnu/microblaze/nt/bin/../lib/gcc/microblaze-xilinx-elf/8.2.0/../../../../microblaze-xilinx-elf/lib/le/crtinit.o: in function `_crtinit': (.text+0x78): undefined reference to` main'

Would be happy for some help in that direction

i tried read similar questions and i expect to understand the concept of linker, compiling etc.

makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
ELFSIZE += \
CodeSample_1.elf.size \
CodeSample_1.elf.size \


# All Target
all: CodeSample_1.elf secondary-outputs

dependents:
    -cd C:/SitalProjects/Refael/Rafael_MicroBlaze_Freertos/prj_Arty22_20191/test_250322/CodeSample_1/Release && $(MAKE) all

# Tool invocations
CodeSample_1.elf: $(OBJS) ../src/lscript.ld $(USER_OBJS) C:/SitalProjects/Refael/Rafael_MicroBlaze_Freertos/prj_Arty22_20191/test_250322/CodeSample_1/Release/CodeSample_1.elf
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: MicroBlaze gcc linker'
    mb-gcc -L../../CodeSample_bsp/microblaze_mcs_0_microblaze_I/lib -Wl,-Map=file_map.map -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -mlittle-endian -mcpu=v11.0 -mxl-soft-mul -Wl,--no-relax -Wl,--gc-sections -o "CodeSample_1.elf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

CodeSample_1.elf.size: CodeSample_1.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: MicroBlaze Print Size'
    mb-size CodeSample_1.elf  |tee "CodeSample_1.elf.size"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(S_UPPER_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(ELFSIZE) CodeSample_1.elf
    -@echo ' '

secondary-outputs: $(ELFSIZE)

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:
C:/SitalProjects/Refael/Rafael_MicroBlaze_Freertos/prj_Arty22_20191/test_250322/CodeSample_1/Release/CodeSample_1.elf:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: Are you compiling and linking with the file containing the `main` function? What does the `main` function look like?

Comment: Are you compiling and linking with the file containing the main function- how? i not used to do any of these   .  i have just regular main : int main()
{.....}

Comment: Well, your `main` function must be in a file. Is that file part of the project you are trying to compile?

Comment: it is under my_app_project --->src --->main.cc .

Comment: ... and is that file in your project file? What IDE are you using? Does it have a menu where you can `Add file to project"? How are you compiling the project? Do you have a Makefile? Anything?

Comment: i use xilinx sdk 2019.1 . i have makefile on debug folder. i can add files too..i compiling by building the application project

Comment: Please edit the question and add the makefile to the question

Comment: i get different error now. fatal error on  #include <string> line

Comment: That's just one of many makefiles used by the project it seems. In which of the makefiles do you mention `main.cc` ?

Comment: in the debug folder of application project . but i got now different string error :  fatal error on #include <string>

Comment: If that's the whole message something seems broken.

Comment: what exactly ? how makefile can be understood?

Comment: Every line starting with `-include ` will include another makefile (if it exists). From the makefile you've shown it looks like you should see the actual commands it uses so if `atal error on #include <string>` is the only output you get, I'd be surprised. The only way I see that happening is if something is broken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: problem has been solved